# Newman's elementary proof of prime number theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

The proof can be found on this site.

[Newman's "Natural proof"(Analytic) of Prime Number Theorem (1980)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466388/newmans-natural-proofanalytic-of-prime-number-theorem-1980?rq=1)

I do not understand well for part(VI), why do we consider such integral would imply $\theta(x)$~$x$ ?

Any one can elaborate a bit for me? Thank you.

Comment: Could you be more precise about your question " why do we consider such integral would imply $\theta(x)$~$x$ ?" Answer: Because it proves PNT?

Comment: @DietrichBurde  To be more precise, I cannot see the link between this integral and the $\theta(x)$~$x$.

Comment: The link is $(V)$. If the integral is not convergent, this contradicts $(V)$. Hence we must have $\theta(x)\sim x$, which is the PNT.

Comment: Am voting to close since this problem is entirely subsumed by the linked question unless the OP still does not understand.